# How to read the simple html dom's result

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to use the simple html dom

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($my_url);
$items = $html->find($my_parser);
```

I can't read my $items

```
die(print_r($items));
```

And I have This error

"Le site Web a rencontré une erreur inattendue. Veuillez essayer de nouveau plus tard."

Any idea please?
Thank you

Comment: try translating the text you get as response. It says "The website has encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later".

Comment: Thanks :) It's "The website has encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: May the url what you try to load give you this response.

Comment: When I try die('msg'); before $items = $html->find($my_parser); It give me 'msg'. And my Url is ok

Comment: try print_r($html->load_file($my_url)); and see what response you get.

Comment: It gives me an empty array!!

Comment: then the response is empty?

Comment: yes it's empty!

Comment: Then you got to check why the response is empty. May be some restriction from the site not load it in this way? or is the url correct? what if you open the url using a browser?

Comment: The url opens the website normally.. Can you tell me more please about restriction? How can I check it? Thank you

Comment: can you tell me what url are you trying to load?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/

Comment: die(print_r($html->load("<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>We're here</p></body></html>"))); returns a big data

Comment: Looks like https://davidwalsh.name/ is taking much memory to load.

Comment: Then what can I do ? Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I can read the error better now

> Error : Call to a member function find() on null dans simple_html_dom->find()..

the function is

```
function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
    return $this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
}
```

and die('root = '.$this->root); returns null